# Why doesn't this zsh script run?

Tags: git, zsh

I have a script:

```bash
for k in $(git branch -r --merged master| egrep -v "^(  origin\/master|  origin\/dev|  origin\/HEAD)"); do do
  if [ -z "$(git log -1 --before='2022-11-01 00:00' -s $k)" ]; then
    echo "$k"
  fi
done
```

This gives me a `fatal: unrecognized argument` error when run in MacOS terminal. However this runs perfectly fine:

```bash
for k in $(git branch -r --merged | sed /\*/d); do
  if [ -z "$(git log -1 --since='2022-11-01 00:00' -s $k)" ]; then
    echo "$k"
  fi
done
```

The git book clearly states that both are supported:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

What goes wrong?

Comment: `for item in $(anything)` is itself bad practice; see [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: ...that said, "MacOS terminal" can mean several different things, but _by default_ the shell in that terminal is zsh, not bash. Are you sure you're tagging correctly? Also, what does running `set -x` before running your code say? (You can turn trace logging back off after with `set +x`)

Comment: Note also that `-s $k` should be `-s "$k"` if your shell is in fact bash (or anything else that complies with the POSIX sh standard); for a shell to let you get away with leaving off quotes it has to explicitly break the standard (as zsh does).

Comment: BTW, I'd suggest `grep -Fv '*'` instead of `sed /\*/d`; less to go wrong. Backslashes in shell change their meaning whenever you're inside a command substitution that used backticks instead of `$( )`, and they're otherwise unnecessarily context-sensitive. Similarly, `*` in a regex doesn't match itself, but instead is a modifier to the prior character, so you need to be sure in `/\*/d` that the backslash is passed to `sed` instead of consumed by the shell (and thus unavailable to `sed`).

Comment: You are absolutely right, this is for zsh although the code was for bash originally.

Comment: The only difference being the parameters for the `git` call, I wonder if they both provide output when run by themselves without all the scripting cruft

Comment: (btw, part of why I ask for the question to be edited to provide `set -x` logs is so we can get a better idea of which command is emitting the `unrecognized argument` message; I have some guesses, but right now they're just guesses, and answers are supposed to be authoritative. Also, have you checked whether replacing the `sed` with the `grep` command suggested above resolves the issue?).

Comment: @eftshift0 yeah both run fine without the bash context.

Comment: Which command exactly produces the error message? Did you check with `set -x` that the correct arguments are passed?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Comment: @user1934428 I have changed the code for a bit so now it doesn't show error anymore. The first line now reads `for k in $(git branch -r --merged master| egrep -v "^(  origin\/master|  origin\/dev|  origin\/HEAD)"); do`

Comment: Please update your question by showing the new code. It's easier to read.  So, if there is no error anymore, is the issue resolved?

Comment: Thanks, I edited. I think it's resolved, anyway I can close it?